# Build on Vercel with Prisma is not working recently (how to include schema.prisma file?)

Tags: build, package.json, prisma, vercel, sveltekit

I developed SvelteKit app with Prisma and am trying to deploy it on Vercel.

In `package.json`, configuration below should be set so that `schema.prisma` file located in root path is available when app is deployed.

```
"postbuild": "cp prisma/schema.prisma .vercel_build_output/functions/node/render/ && cp node_modules/@prisma/engines/*query* .vercel_build_output/functions/node/render/",
```

Problem is an error occurred during the build on Vercel, but that wasn't occurred before (~ May 2022).

I guess cause of the error is related to recent update of SvelteKit and found that directory of `.vercel_build_output` that is generated during the build is changed to the new `.vercel` recently. However, the new path structure for `index.js` (i.e. `.vercel/output/functions/render.func/home/s/test/discord-bot-frontend/.svelte-kit/output/server/index.js`) is so different from the previous (i.e. `.vercel_build_output/functions/node/render/`) that I cannot find right path for it.

#### Would you please let me know right setting for `package.json`?

##### Error message:

```
> discord-bot-frontend@0.0.1 postbuild
> cp prisma/schema.prisma .vercel_build_output/functions/node/render/ && cp node_modules/@prisma/engines/*query* .vercel_build_output/functions/node/render/
cp: cannot create regular file ‘.vercel_build_output/functions/node/render/’: No such file or directory
Error: Command "npm run vercel-build" exited with 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that there is no need to modify `.vercel_build_output` now. In other words, the `post build` is not needed anymore.

It is probably because latest Vercel handles [this point](https://youtu.be/OUzaUJ3gEug?t=24974).